Parsing broken multipart/mixed email
I'm trying to use perl Email::MIME to capture the multipart/mixed portion of an email into a buffer. I have a script that I've been using for a long time that is now having a problem with a particular email, and I think it's because the email is not formatted properly.
use Email::MIME;
my $buf;
while(<STDIN> ){
        $buf .= $_;
}
my @mailData;
my $msg = Email::MIME->new($buf);
my @parts = $msg->parts;
my $desc = $msg->debug_structure;
print "descr: $desc\n";
 $msg->walk_parts(sub {
     my ($part) = @_;
     #warn($part->content_type . ": " . $part->subparts);
     my $content_type = $msg->content_type;
     if (($content_type =~ m/multipart\/mixed/i) && !@mailData) {
             @mailData = split( '\n', $part->body);
        print $part->body;
     }
     elsif (($part->content_type =~ m/text\/plain$/i) && !@mailData) { 
        @mailData = split( '\n', $part->body);
     }
 });

Here are the relevant sections of the email, exactly as displayed, including the two hyphen lines:
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============7958309719180706421=="
Content-Length: 8034
Status: RO
X-Status: 
X-Keywords: NonJunk         
X-UID: 2

--===============7958309719180706421==

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sending command: "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line 
Drive command "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line
    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

system security tool that allows system administrators to set authentication
policy without having to recompile programs that handle authentication.

The above code adds the body text to @mailData but only the text after the second line of hyphens. It just skips over it entirely and only collects the text starting with "system security tool".
It also prints this description showing the parts:
descr: + multipart/mixed; boundary="===============7958309719180706421=="
     + 
     + text/plain; charset="utf-8"

The text/plain part, as it displays in an email client, appears to be only the mailing list info, not the actual body content.
Is this a bug in Email::MIME? Or am I not processing the parts correctly?
Edit: Here is a link to the full original email
https://pastebin.com/F5MbSfYm

If this is only this specific mail I would rather suspect an improperly formed email. For example it might have plain \r instead of \n somewhere, have some spaces between mime header and body instead of a really empty line etc. Such aspects are invisible though when just looking in a text editor and completely lost when you copy + paste the relevant parts into the question here. So one can only speculate what might be going on. One would need to have the real binary mail or anything stripped down which stll shows the problems for further analysis.

Thanks so much for your help. Here is the full email. I'll also add it to the body of my post.
https://pastebin.com/F5MbSfYm

This looks for me like a problem with Email::MIME, but also with the mail itself:

The first MIME part has no MIME header and thus should be text/plain with US-ASCII (see RFC 2046) - but it is obviously utf-8. This is a problem in the mail.
Looks like Email::MIME cannot properly deal with MIME parts which have no MIME header.

The latter problem is actually known for 10 years and proposed patches seem to exist for 8 years - see https://github.com/rjbs/Email-MIME/issues/14

I'm using version 1.954 - doesn't that already contain the patch you reference?

and given that Email::MIME isn't able to parse these messages, do you have any suggestions for how I might proceed when it fails?

@AlexRegan: the issue I've linked to is still open for 10 years and I cannot see from the issue that the proposed patches were applied. As for suggestions on what to do: try to apply the patches yourself or use another parser like MIME-Tools

It looks like the patch fixed it for now, thanks
